# airflow 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_paused',how to fix it?

Tags: python, airflow

I am new to airflow and I just follow the tutorial to run a dag. Actually I did it successfully, but the problem is when I try to pause the dag by inputing command line like `airflow pause dag_id`,it throws `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_paused'`

And the Traceback is:

```
File "/anaconda3/bin/airflow", line 32, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 365, in pause
    set_is_paused(True, args, dag)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 379, in set_is_paused
    dm.is_paused = is_paused
```

So I check the python file in the output directory, however, it was coded by airflow and I don't know how to fix it?!!!

```
SHOW:~ macbook$ airflow list_dags
[2018-09-07 21:31:38,262] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2018-09-07 21:31:38,381] {models.py:258} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/macbook/airflow/dags


-------------------------------------------------------------------
DAGS
-------------------------------------------------------------------
example_bash_operator
example_branch_dop_operator_v3
example_branch_operator
example_http_operator
example_kubernetes_executor
example_kubernetes_operator
example_passing_params_via_test_command
example_python_operator
example_short_circuit_operator
example_skip_dag
example_subdag_operator
example_subdag_operator.section-1
example_subdag_operator.section-2
example_trigger_controller_dag
example_trigger_target_dag
example_xcom
haha
latest_only
latest_only_with_trigger
test_utils
tutorial

SHOW:~ macbook$ airflow pause haha
[2018-09-07 21:35:41,366] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2018-09-07 21:35:41,496] {models.py:258} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/macbook/airflow/dags
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/bin/airflow", line 32, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 365, in pause
    set_is_paused(True, args, dag)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 379, in set_is_paused
    dm.is_paused = is_paused
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_paused'
```

Comment: "I just follow the tutorial to run a dag" --> Could you add your script or series of commands you have used here?

Comment: @FlyingTeller https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html  This is the script I copy and I input : 'airflow backfill tutorial -s 2015-06-01 -e 2015-06-07' to run a dag

Comment: Can you see an active dag by executing `airflow list_dags`?

Comment: yeah.I can see it

Comment: Can you add the output of `airflow list_dags` and the exact `airflow pause` command you are running?

Comment: @cwurtz I have shown the whole information above. You can help me check it.

Comment: Which version of Airflow are you using

Comment: @joeb I've fixed it. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the DAG (tutorial.py) is not in the directory where airflow expects the DAGs. Please check that the DAG is stored in the directory set in airflow.cfg under `dags_folder`.

Comment: Hi! I've figured out the problem. It is because the airflow scheduler updates its dags by an interval.And it needs some time to wait before the scheduler is aware of the new dag's join.

Comment: @XiuchaoWu do you have any idea, how long does scheduler take to be aware of new dag's join?

Answer (score -1):

If you're reading any files using that code snippet, make sure to include the full path. Relative paths won't work.